# How to make phone calls from one PC to another

Tags: 11.10, phone

I have 2 Ubuntu PCs (Not in the same physical place) and I want to call from my PC to the other. What apps does Ubuntu have for making phone calls from PC-to-PC.

UPDATED - Forgot to mention that it should not be Skype or Google Talk. In the case of Skype because we are actually looking for an alternative to it to call one another. For the Google Talk plugin because the need to have a web browser opened to use it is not what we need.

Comment: Call? Voip? Skype..

Comment: Sorry updated question to include that it should not be Skype nor should it need a web browser opened to work like the Google Talk plugin inside the gmail account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twinkle: `sudo apt-get install twinkle`

Soft-phone for making telephone calls using SIP over an IP network.

Twinkle supports direct IP phone to IP phone communication or a network
using a SIP proxy to route your calls.

In addition to making basic voice calls Twinkle provides you the
following features regardless of the services that your VoIP service
provider might offer.

2 call appearances (lines)
 Multiple active call identities
 Custom ring tones
 Call Waiting
 Call Hold
 3-way conference calling
 Mute
 Call redirection on demand
 Call redirection unconditional
 Call redirection when busy
 Call redirection no answer
 Reject call redirection request
 Blind call transfer
 Call transfer with consultation (attended call transfer) (new)
 Reject call transfer request
 Call reject
 Repeat last call
 Do not disturb
 Auto answer
 Message Waiting Indication
 Voice mail speed dial
 User definable scripts triggered on call events
  E.g. to implement selective call reject or distinctive ringing
 RFC 2833 DTMF events
 In-band DTMF
 Out-of-band DTMF (SIP INFO)
 STUN support for NAT traversal
 Send NAT keep alive packets when using STUN
 NAT traversal through static provisioning
 Missed call indication
 History of call detail records for incoming, outgoing, successful and missed
 DNS SRV support
 Automatic fail-over to an alternate server if a server is unavailable
 Other programs can originate a call via Twinkle, e.g. call from address book
 System tray icon
 System tray menu to originate and answer calls while Twinkle stays hidden
 User definable number conversion rules
 Simple address book
 Support for UDP and TCP (new) as transport for SIP
 Presence
 Instant messaging
 Simple file transfer with instant message
 Instant message composition indication
 Command line interface (CLI)

VoIP security
 Secure voice communication by ZRTP/SRTP
 MD5 digest authentication support for all SIP requests
 AKAv1-MD5 digest authentication support for all SIP requests (new)
 Identity hiding

Audio codecs
 G.711 A-law (64 kbps payload, 8 kHz sampling rate)
 G.711 u-law (64 kbps payload, 8 kHz sampling rate)
 GSM (13 kbps payload, 8 kHz sampling rate)
 Speex narrow band (15.2 kbps payload, 8 kHz sampling rate)
 Speex wide band (28 kbps payload, 16 kHz sampling rate)
 Speex ultra wide band (36 kbps payload, 32 kHz sampling rate)
 G.726 (16, 24, 32 or 40 kbps payload, 8 kHz sampling rate)

For all codecs the following preprocessing options are available to improve
quality at the far end of a call.
 Automatic gain control (AGC) (new)
 Noise reduction (new)
 Voice activity detection (VAD) (new)
 Acoustic echo control (AEC) [experimental] (new)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ekiga (http://ekiga.org/). It's in the software center and works like other softphones, supporting VOIP, but they also have a free sip to sip service built into it. Give it a try

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoftPhone, will give you a list of SIP & VoIP compatible software. It should give you a start.

There is also Skype and Google Talk that may be helpful. Google Talk requires only a very small plugin and Skype can be installed easily enough. Google talk is not in the repositories from Ubuntu, but Skype is.

Comment: Skype is, Google talk isn't in the repos.